# Sistema de grid no Ionic

Tags: html5, css3, ionic2, grid

Estou querendo criar uma tela de login responsiva, minha tela tem apenas três elementos, uma imagem no meio e mais dois botoes, cada elemento em uma row do "ionic grid"... gostaria de definir uma forma de manter sempre os botes no final da tela e a imagem no meio da mesma independente do tamanho da tela "responsivo"...eu pensei em definir uma quantidade de rows, se é que isso é possível para poder manter algumas rows vazias servindo como espaçamento pros elementos da tela, mas não sei como farei isso, alguem poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

para colocar os 2 botões embaixo pode usar o ION-FOOTER, que eles já ficam na parte debaixo, ja a imagem no meio, pode definir a margim top de 50% ou seja, ela vai ficar sempre no meio da tela.
img {
    width: Tamanho da imagem;
    margin: 50% auto 0 auto;
    }

OBS: Aconselho você a tentar aprender Flex box, vai facilitar muito sua vida